# Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE and Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.0.RELEASE - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_5_2

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm going to add `Spring Data Elasticsearch` support into my existing `Spring Boot 1.5.1` application with `Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE`.

I have added a following Maven dependency into my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and right now my application fails during startup with a following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_5_2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'elasticsearchClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_5_2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_5_5_2
    at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:140)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:143)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.node(NodeBuilder.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.createNodeClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.createClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.elasticsearchClient(ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42d9c766.CGLIB$elasticsearchClient$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42d9c766$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$450abfed.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$42d9c766.elasticsearchClient(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <neo4j.version>3.1.0</neo4j.version>
        <guava.version>19.0-rc1</guava.version>
        <owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>20160924.1</owasp-java-html-sanitize.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-security-enterprise</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer</groupId>
            <artifactId>owasp-java-html-sanitizer</artifactId>
            <version>${owasp-java-html-sanitize.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How to properly configure `Spring Boot 1.5.1` with `Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.0.RELEASE` and `Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.0.RELEASE` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions of Lucene that elastic search and Neo4j require are different. Spring Data Neo4j will only use the Lucene library if you are using the `neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver` and if you specify the version of `neo4j` to use. In your pom you specify all three drivers: bolt, http and embedded.

First determine which driver you really need. Only specify that driver. If you use the embedded driver you will need to add another dependency to add the version of Neo4j you want to use. When you include this dependency in your pom, you will have to exclude lucene (or alternatively tell spring data elasticsearch to exclude lucene).

You will also have to realise that if you use the latter option that you may have incompatibilities in related libraries. Ideally you will want to use versions of the Spring Data projects that use the same major and minor semver for Lucene.